# How to fix error after deploying bot with azure?

Tags: azure, botframework

I have followed the steps to deploy a bot [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) using code from the example [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/03.welcome-users)

This is my project directory structure before I zip it

```
├── bots
├── deploymentTemplates
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
└── web.config
```

After deploying my zip file with

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "<resource-group-name>" --name "<name-of-web-app>" --src "code.zip"
```

I am returned a url `https://my-chatbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest` If I go to this url it gives me an error

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Illegal characters in path.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentStatusFile.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Open>b__0() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentStatusFile.cs:line 56\r\n...
```

I can show more of the error if you need me to, though I'm not sure what path it is talking about

EDIT:

A day later and I changed nothing with this deployment but the url is fixed now and I get no errors... Until I go to test my bot in webchat

now every message I try to send is stuck sending and under **bot management** > **channels** it gives me this error "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable"

Comment: Must be related https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2893

Comment: Can you show more of the error you are getting? Also, have you zipped your project files correctly along with being in the right root folder ?

Comment: I have updated my post with changes

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by a rogue "app_offline.html" file in the root directory of my deployment in kudu, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045217/getting-site-under-construction-message-after-azure-webapp-deployment) for details. As soon as I deleted it I have the app working now :)